# Python: Element-wise mean of lists in a dataframe conditioned on another column

Tags: python, pandas, apply, mean, elementwise-operations

I have a dataframe looking like this with three columns (10 different stimuli, 16 trials and a data column containing lists of equal lengths). I would simply like to get the element-wise mean of the data column based on the stimulus. As I have 10 different stimuli, it should result in 10 arrays for each stimulus which also are the mean of all data arrays over trials.

[image]

I thought about something like this but it gives me somewthing really weird.

```
df.groupby('stimulus').apply(np.mean)
>> IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

[image]

---

## Build my dataframe

```
trial_vec       = np.tile(np.arange(16)+1, 10)     
stimulus_vec    = np.repeat([-2., -1.75, -1., -0.75, -0.5,  0.5,  1.,  1.25,  1.75,  2.5 ], 16)                  
data_vec        = np.random.randint(0, 16, size=160)
df              = pd.DataFrame({'trial': trial_vec, 'stimulus': stimulus_vec, 'data': data_vec}).astype('object')
df["data"]      = [np.random.rand(4).tolist() for i in range(160)]
df
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need. What is the element wise mean?

Comment: This seems fundamentally like a bad design... lists in data-frames rarely make sense. If you want element-wise means, use *numpy* arrays.

Comment: How else would you store the data? My original list have the size 1x35000. Due to 16 trials for 10 stimuli each i have 160 of these lists. I thought that would be a convenient way to store them.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert `data` in each group to a 2d list which makes sure the object can be converted to a 2d numpy array *when the number of elements in each cell of the data column are the same*, and then take `mean` over `axis=0` (column-wise mean):

```
df.groupby('stimulus').data.apply(lambda g: np.mean(g.values.tolist(), axis=0))

#stimulus
#-2.00    [0.641834320107, 0.427639804593, 0.42733812964...
#-1.75    [0.622484839138, 0.529860126072, 0.63310754064...
#-1.00    [0.546323060494, 0.465573022088, 0.54947320390...
#-0.75    [0.431675052484, 0.367636755052, 0.45263194597...
#-0.50    [0.423135952819, 0.544110613089, 0.55496058720...
# 0.50    [0.421858616927, 0.439204977418, 0.43153540636...
# 1.00    [0.612239664017, 0.499305567037, 0.46284515082...
# 1.25    [0.498544756769, 0.481073640317, 0.43564801829...
# 1.75    [0.51821909334, 0.44904063908, 0.358509374567,...
# 2.50    [0.465606275355, 0.516448419224, 0.33715002349...
#Name: data, dtype: object
```

Or `stack` data as a 2d array, and then take `mean` over `axis=0`:

```
df.groupby('stimulus').data.apply(lambda g: np.mean(np.stack(g), axis=0))
```

---

Edit: if you have `nan`s in the *data* column, you can use `np.nanmean` to calculate `mean` without `nan`s:

```
df.groupby('stimulus').data.apply(lambda g: np.nanmean(np.stack(g), axis=0))
```

Comment: Nice and concise. I forgot to mention that I have NaN values inside my datacolumn instead of lists as well. Probably that's why your solution doesn't work for me: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. But maybe others will 2D lists without NaNs, I think then your answer is very neat.

Comment: If you have `nans` in *data*, you can use `np.nanmean` which calculates the average without `nan`.

Comment: I think that only works if I have lists of NaN of the same lengths right? Because if I have single NaN values, not in a list but a single NaN in the cell.

Comment: Then you would need to drop na from the series before calculating `mean`, i.e. something like `...np.mean(np.stack(g.dropna()), axis=0)`.

Answer (score 3):

#### An update

This is actually a rare usecase for a grouper not in the current DataFrame.

```
df['data'].apply(pd.Series).groupby(df['stimulus']).mean()
```

#### Original

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do but you typically should not have lists in your dataframe. I would properly format your data first and then take the mean of each column by group.

```
data_proper = df['data'].apply(pd.Series)
df_new = pd.concat([df.drop('data',axis=1), data_proper], axis=1)
df_new.head()

  stimulus trial         0         1         2         3
0       -2     1  0.046361  0.967723  0.707726  0.708462
1       -2     2  0.270566  0.778324  0.638878  0.276983
2       -2     3  0.261356  0.563411  0.639114  0.111150
3       -2     4  0.124745  0.532362  0.869781  0.142513
4       -2     5  0.707596  0.137417  0.493232  0.098975

df_new.groupby('stimulus').mean()

                 0         1         2         3
stimulus                                        
-2.00     0.516795  0.458579  0.527230  0.360560
-1.75     0.418950  0.497287  0.442577  0.518487
-1.00     0.569175  0.350724  0.429025  0.562950
-0.75     0.474533  0.517560  0.472101  0.658333
-0.50     0.481185  0.426829  0.414059  0.571252
 0.50     0.432719  0.563101  0.421617  0.531289
 1.00     0.478947  0.412383  0.458543  0.590503
 1.25     0.596648  0.520953  0.515184  0.513206
 1.75     0.492729  0.524673  0.567336  0.465172
 2.50     0.369798  0.540603  0.499210  0.605297
```

Or in one continuous line inspired by @Scott Boston

```
df.drop('data', axis=1)\
  .assign(**df.data.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('col'))\
  .groupby('stimulus').mean()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input! Also thanks for visualizing your steps, that helps a lot with understanding. In your last step, when you group by stimulus and then take the mean, what happens to the column 'trials'?

Comment: Also, and I know you don't like it, but I would need my old structure back, meaning that all datapoints will be in a list again (I store multiple of those outputs in an excel file later and the code only works, if the data is in a list). Do you know how to reconstruct "df_new" to my original format?

Answer (score 0):

By using `reduce` and `operator.add`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import operator
from functools import reduce
df.groupby('stimulus').data.apply(lambda l : np.array(list(reduce(lambda x, y: map(operator.add, x,y), l)))/len(l))
```